# flutter schedule local notification by workManager

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

Is it possible to schedule notification from background dart code?

For example, like using `work_manager` plugin from `executeTask` method as if I register service that runs every hour and schedule today notification base on current location.

I tried out but no luck.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? Since I am having the exact same issue

Comment: yes, I had to create custom flutter plugin and run your plugin code as periodic from `work_manager`

Comment: Can you share your code on github or anywhere esle

Answer (score 1):

In order schedule notifications work you should add lines below. Solution is this: add these lines after `</activity>` in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
```

Comment: it is continuation of answer of bshears below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to schedule Local notification with the help of work manager. When I was trying the Flutter Local Notification Plugin on my Xiaomi device, the notification is not showing when the app is closed ( and cleared from the recent activity). So the only solution I found was to use the Work Manager flutter plugin to show() directly without scheduling.

**PROS**

- Work Manager helped me to show notifications after the app closed and cleared from the recent app list.
- It will work even after the device    restart

**CONS**

- The notification will not show up sometimes.
- The scheduling to fixed time cannot be managed. (android sometimes does not allow to execute task if the app is closed)

```
callbackDispatcher() {
Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
if (LocalNotification.flutterNotificationPlugin == null) {
await LocalNotification.Initializer();
}
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
var hour = inputData['hour'];
var minute = inputData['minute'];
DateTime time = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, minute);
await LocalNotification.ShowOneTimeNotification(time);
return Future.value(true);
});
}
```

Trigger

```
FlatButton(
child: Text('set'),
onPressed: () async {
await Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher);
await Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
"test_workertask", "test_workertask",
inputData: {"data1": "value1", "data2": "value2"},
frequency: Duration(hours: 1),
initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 10),
existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.replace);
},
),
```

Comment: i have the same problem . can you help me , @J. MARS

Comment: There used to be a command to execute registered periodic task immediately in the workmanager  pub documentation but it is gone. Any idea what was the command to run in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#scheduling-a-notification) by reusing snippet below:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

var duration = Duration(hours: 1);
var scheduledNotificationDateTime = DateTime.now().add(duration);

var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your other channel id',
    'your other channel name', 
    'your other channel description',
);

var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
   androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, 
   iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
    0, 
    'scheduled title', 
    'scheduled body', 
    scheduledNotificationDateTime, 
    platformChannelSpecifics,
);
```

Comment: this is jest going to schedule notification after 1 hour and can't run from isolate like `workManager` plugin